# Make imported modules private to other modules

Tags: python, import, python-import

Suppose I have a code like this in module `a.py`

```
import numpy as np

def sqrt(x):
  return np.sqrt(x)
```

And I have a module `b.py` written like this:

```
import a
print(a.sqrt(25))
print(a.np.sqrt(25))
```

I will see that the code runs fine and that when using autocomplete in most IDEs, I found that `a.np` is accessible. I want to make `a.np` private so that only `a` code can see that variable.
I don't want `b` to be able to access `a.np`.

What is a good approach to make this possible?

Why do I want `a.np` to be inaccessible? Because I want it to not show in the autocomplete when I type `a.` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Jupyter Lab. It hides what the modules can do because there are so many imports that I use in my module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the same as for "protected" attributes / methods in a class (names defined in a module are actually - at runtime - attributes of the module object): prefix those names with a single leading underscore, ie

```
import numpy as _np

def sqrt(x):
  return _np.sqrt(x)
```

Note that this will NOT prevent someone to use `a._np.sqrt(x)`, but at least it makes it quite clear that he is using a protected attribute.

Comment: Is there a way that I don't have to rename all my variables or a smarter way to structure the code entirely? Because I think that no one wants to use `_np` in their code.

Comment: I don't know how Jupyter handles auto-completion (and I'm not going to install it to try out), but you can always try to define `__all__` in your module (cf https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) - if Jupyter uses this attribute it might solve the issue, else, well, you'll either have to do a search/replace or live with it.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 approaches here:

1. more user-friendly solution: change alias names to "underscored" ones

   ```
   import numpy as _np
   ...
   ```

   this will not prevent from importing it, but it will say to user that this are implementation details and one should not depend on them.
2. preferred-by-me solution: do nothing, leave it as it is, use semver and bump versions accordingly.

Comment: hint: the resolution of the name `np` in the `sqrt` function happens at runtime... What do you think will happens when calling `a.sqrt` when `a.np` isn't defined anymore ?